# How to migrate Diego apps to DEA in Bluemix?

Tags: python-2.7, ibm-cloud, cloud-foundry, ibm-cloud-tools, diego

I have created a python app in my dashboard and I want to migrate it to DEA before deploying my code there. I have tried cf command 
`cf disable-diego <APP_NAME>` in CLI
however,  it returned 
`Error: CF-BackendSelectionNotAuthorized - You cannot select the backend on which to run this application
{
   "description": "You cannot select the backend on which to run this application",
   "error_code": "CF-BackendSelectionNotAuthorized",
   "code": 320005
}`

I want to have my app in DEA before I deploy code there and then I'll migrate it to Diego. This is part of my testing.

Comment: Can you explain why you want to run your program on a older architecture (DEA) when you can run it on Diego?

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to contact your Bluemix provider on this. Cloud Controller has a flag that controls whether non-admins are allowed to switch between Diego and DEA, and it looks like that's disabled on your system.
https://github.com/cloudfoundry/cloud_controller_ng/blob/ebcc9658a4f3db27bfbb984831bf0428d46f54d8/bosh/jobs/cloud_controller_ng/spec#L522

DEAs are being phased out. I wonder why you need to test it on DEA first.